# Reading Key from SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to read a `SequenceFile` in my MapReduce program with input format for the `Mapper` as `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat`. The sequence file has a `IntWritable` as key and `ArrayWritable` as value.

```
job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.class);
```

Mapper gets BytesWritable as key and value.

```
public void map(BytesWritable key, BytesWritable value, Context context)
```

Now I am trying to convert the key back to `IntWritable` but I am getting a `NumberFormatException`. Looks like I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(new String(key.getBytes())));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BytesWritable class exposes the raw binary representation of the data (what ever type it happens to be). If you were storing numbers, then the raw binary representation is determined by what the serialization class of the number was. It's almost certainly not going to look like nice text like "123" which is what parseInt is expecting. More likely it's some chunk of bytes like 1A34E56C... etc depending on the output serialization format.

If your data is actually text, you're probably better off with just TextInputFormat. On the other hand, if you know what the data type of your file is, then just SequenceFile is better. SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat is good for when you need to access the raw representation of the data on disk (e.g., if you're missing a class to deserialize the data, and need to provide one yourself).

Comment: the sequence file I have has a `IntWritable` for key and `ArrayWritable` extended to hold Text for values. Now the reason I chose to use `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat` is to read the values back in Text (converting the `BytesWritable`). If I use `SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat` it returns `SequenceFileAsTextRecordReader` for the reader and `Text` for key and value. `toString` is called for the values and for `ArrayWritable` it returns something like ` com.jerry.hadoop.sequencefile.TextArrayWritable@16c163fcom`

Comment: Since you already know the key value types, why not just use straight up SequenceFileInputFormat?

Comment: That worked. I changed the mapper's key to `IntWritable` and value to `TextArrayWritable`. How does the `SequenceFileRecordReader` know the types of key and value at runtime ? reflection ?

Comment: The data type classnames are stored in the sequencefile. Then the classes are instantiated using reflection, yes.